# How do I get the JSON content from a JSON string in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

My JSON string(this is what i get after making the request in $.post )-

```
{"email":"bill gates"}
{"email":"steve jobs"}
{"email":"mark zuckerberg"}
{"email":"cristiano ronaldo"}
{"email":"wayne rooney"}
```

The code I am using to get the content-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = new Object();
    data.email = "yash.mathur13@gmail.com";
    var dataString = $.toJSON(data);
    $.post('templates/chat.php', {
        data: dataString
    }, function(json) {
$("body").append(json);
    });
});
```

I want to dislay each one of them in an `<li>` tag.

Comment: What did you try? Rentacoder.com is just around the corner... Here at SO we answer _questions_ about pieces of code that you have already written; this is not a "write my code for me" website.

Comment: Also, that is not valid JSON. That is five _separate_ pieces of individually-valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
var list = "<ul></ul>";
$.each(json, function(idx, value) {
    list.append("<li>" + value.email + "</li>");
});
$("body").append("list");
```

Comment: I think it should be:

`$("body").append(list);` instead of `$("body").append("list");`

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

should be able to do

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
 $.each(obj, function(index, item){
     // append to your <ul> if it already exists, or build one up
     $('ul').append('<li>' + item.email + '</li>');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually encode things to JSON with jQuery, usually.

Does the following Javascript work instead?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = new Object();
    data.email = "yash.mathur13@gmail.com";
    $.post('templates/chat.php', data, function(response) {
        $("body").append('<ul>' + response.map(function(elm) {
            return '<li>' + elm + '</li>';
        }).join('') + '</ul>');
    });
});
```