# JQuery ajax function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Can anyone find out what is the error in this code? 
Im trying to make a call to my API Controller which returns JsonObject. It hits the controller and result is shown in the Chrome > preview. However, when I try to access on success function, it shows undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

CallService();
});

function CallService() {
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/Java/Controller/Method",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "script",
    success: function (data) {

        alert('success '+ data);

    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('error ' + data);
    }
 });
}
```

Interestingly, I only able hit the controller if I put my dataType: "script". In the case of json or jsonp. I couldnt hit event hit the controller.

**EDIT**

Console log on using dataType : "jsonp"

```
  object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function,     setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
  abort: function (a){var b=a||u;return i&&i.abort(b),x(0,b),this}
  always: function (){return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}
  complete: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}
  done: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}
   error: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}
   fail: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}
  getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return 2===t?f:null}
  getResponseHeader: function (a){var b;if(2===t){if(!j){j={};while(b=Dc.exec(f))j[b[1].toLowerCase()]=b[2]}b=j[a.toLowerCase()]}return null==b?null:b}
  overrideMimeType: function (a){return t||(k.mimeType=a),this}
  pipe: function (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}
   progress: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}
   promise: function (a){return null!=a?n.extend(a,d):d}
   readyState: 4
   setRequestHeader: function (a,b){var c=a.toLowerCase();return t||(a=s[c]=s[c]||a,r[a]=b),this}
   state: function (){return c}
   status: 200
   statusCode: function (a){var b;if(a)if(2>t)for(b in a)q[b]=[q[b],a[b]];else v.always(a[v.status]);return this}
   statusText: "success"
   success: function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}
   then: function (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}
   __proto__: Object
```

Comment: remove   dataType: "script", and try

Comment: Then I get error [Object Object]

Comment: Are you running this from `http://localhost:8080` ? If not, you might be running into [Cross-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) problems.

Comment: yes. Im currently running on localhost:8080

Comment: You need to access sucess data with your jsonObject name which is given in your controller. i.e. data['jsonObjectNname'][0].jsonAttributeName;

Comment: Instead of alert use `console.log(data);` .

Comment: [Object Object] is not a error if u want to access value than u need to write  alert('success '+ data.YOURPROPERTYNAME);

Comment: console.log(data) will give you a whole object data

Comment: @user2412230 Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332074/ in your case Json is already parsed you don't need to parse it .

Comment: My controller return the JsonObj as toString()

Comment: @user2412230, This is not valid json response. First you could check your service to return the data as in json format. You could check the service response in your browser. That Should be in JSON format. This is not the valid json returned from your service.

Comment: @Jeba I can return the Json data from my service. This is my perspective I have a default.html page on my desktop and my API running on tomcat server. I just found this error in console "XMLHttpRequest cannot load  my *url*. Origin is therefore 'null' therefore not allowed access"

Answer (score 2):

```
function CallService() {
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/Java/Controller/Method",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d)
    alert('success '+ data[0].yourvalues);

  },
  error: function (data) {
    alert('error ' + data);
}
});
}
```

Comment: I couldnt hit my API controller if I remove the dataType: "script"

Comment: what if you add dataType: json,

Comment: It doesnt even hit my controller

Comment: I found the bug. Im running my static html pages directly from desktop. Running it as another web project fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
console.log(data);
```

It shows `jsonObject` in your console.

If you wanted to alert data then try this:

```
alert(data.jsonObectName[index].attributeName);
```

here index is object index i.e. start with 0. and attribute name is your value name in object

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://localhost:8080/Java/Controller/Method",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "script",
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert('success '+ data.jsonObectName[index].attributeName);

},
error: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert('error ' + data.jsonObectName[index].attributeName);
}
```

});

Comment: This is my success: function (data) {
            alert("success " + data.ob[0].te name);
        }

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Can you Paste console log here

Comment: function (data) { alert("success " + data.ob[0].te); }  try this

Answer (score 2):

You have the Object in your AJAX success method. Then you could bind the datas from response.

For your reference here i attached the simple JSONP response from the server and bind the values in our UserInterface.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://githubbadge.appspot.com/Jebasuthan',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function (json) {
    console.log(json);
    var result = '<h3>Name: ' + json.user.login + '</h3>' +
                 '<p>Forked Repository: ' + json.fork_repos + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Languages: ' + json.languages + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Email-Id: ' + json.user.email + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Location: ' + json.user.location + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Last Updated Date: ' + json.user.updated_at + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Blog: <a target="_blank" href=' + json.user.blog + '>' + json.user.blog + '</a></p>';
      $('#badge').append(result);
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/9eV8s/1/)

Comment: My API controller will return the JsonString which I need to access it. Im able to hit my controller but I cant access the return value on success function

Comment: @user2412230, I amy ajax call success method console.log i had object. You can check your browser console.log, You have the Objects with values from your service. First you have to check the Response data. Then you have to bind the data from the response like what i did. Otherwise you can share your console.log(data) from your browser. That could help us to find the issue. I will help you to how to bind the data from ajax call success method

Comment: I tried using dataType: "jsonp" and I got error - console.log

Comment: Ill add my console log to this post

Comment: I found the bug. Im running my static html pages directly from desktop. Running it as another web project fixed the problem.

Comment: @user2412230, Ok Goahead, If our example source helpful for you means give your votes ...